# I added a tag, `system-tweak`, but I think it should be `system-tweaks`?

Tags: discussion

I just was typing furiously fast and missed an s on my tag [system-tweak](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-tweak), there.  Now I can't change it!  Does it bother you as much as it bothers me that it's singular and every other tag is plural?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I don't think there's much use in creating that tag whatsoever. We already have: [tweaks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tweaks).

Still, it is very broad, and somewhat redundant. Adding the tag [tweaks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tweaks) (or [system-tweaks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-tweaks) for that matter) doesn't really help to *refine* a question in any way. You definitely want to tweak something specific, so therefore use the specific tag for this (e.g. the Windows Explorer, thumbnails, etc).

<sub>Because of this, I retagged your question to use [tweaks](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tweaks) instead, but expect a request to have that tag removed soon :)</sub>

Comment: tweaks and system-tweaks could overlap.  The problem is when you type system-, "tweaks" doesn't come up.  Not everyone thinks to just type "tweaks".  I know it's a hyponym for "system-tweaks", which is all the more reason for it to occur to someone, right?  But hyponyms aren't heavily practiced in schools, so I think it's too complex a relationship, and the extra tag would therefore be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, also.  It doesn't really answer the question, though. :/

Comment: Well, I don't consider `[tweaks]` to be helpful either, and I assume that if `[system-]` didn't give you anything, you must have surely thought about `[tweaks]` :) Where's the difference between those, even? Also, `[tweaks]` is a *hypernym* for `[system-tweaks]`. What does the "system-" part mean?

Comment: I know it's not a straight answer, but it's a discussion nonetheless, and there's no point whatsoever in creating a tag when we already have one that covers the topic. Talking about pluralization is the least of an issue here.

Comment: Well, it's good to have discussion....  If you observe the same logic you're following, though, "C++" doesn't deserve its own tag because it's an offshoot of "C".  Maybe that's not precise enough.  "Debian" doesn't deserve its own tag because it's a type of "Linux"...?  When I think of "tweaks", I think of software-specific tweaks.  When I think of "system-tweaks", I think about OS tailoring.  The correlation between "tweaks" and "system-tweaks" is complex, so no... I didn't think of it at all.  If I had, I would have used it, though, to be honest.

Comment: About the difference: if you can see that [tweaks] is a *hypernym* for [system-tweaks], then you should be able to see the difference, right?  It's like the difference between [drinks] and [juices].  One group includes the other.  There's more explanation in the previous comment. :)

Comment: I get the principal idea, yet I don't even understand what you mean with `[system-tweaks]`. If `[tweaks]` is software-specific, and `[system-tweaks]` is about the OS, then you have to consider that the operating system is just software too. If it were `[operating-system-tweaks]`, maybe. But still, this tag does not mean anything. What is "tweaking"?

Comment: Also, a snack and a food silo are both groupings of food.  The syntax is radically different, though.  Memory encoding is largely based on the syntactical relationship between groups.  It's also based on pneumonic rehearsal (so, I brought up the lack of practice in hyponyms in schools).  I could go on, but to cut the head off the snake: the foundation of my argument is a subjective one: people are similar.  [Tweaks] didn't occur to me when I thought of [system-tweaks], so I figure it won't occur to many other people when they are looking for [system-tweaks].

Comment: I think this goes way beyond what my basic argument was. I completely understand your idea, but you have to consider that in our (very limited) tag world, we don't even have a real taxonomy. There is no good reason to introduce a new (rather meaningless) tag that is already covered by a meaningless meta-tag. [Read on](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) for an in-depth explanation of why the SE network does not want those.

Comment: Oh, and to answer your question, **yes, it should have been system-tweaks** (plural form) :)

Comment: Is there any way to change a tag after you accidentally commit a spelling error?

Comment: I believe it's due to caching.  You could probably try to remove the tag, wait for a day and then use the right one.

Comment: Interesting reading material.  I don't agree that [tweaks] is a meta-tag, though.  Meta-tags are things like [date=""] or [author=""].  I think that's useless, in general.  Some tags which could are homographically "meta tags" are not included in the article, but they are also useful.  For example, [(device)] (i.e., [ipod]) isn't useful if it describes what the users used to input the question.  It's useful if it describes the content (e.g., "a question about ipods").

Comment: I think including [windows] and [tweaks] is specific enough.  I would subscribe to [system-tweaks] and not [tweaks], also, though.  So I have a new question.  Is there a way to subscribe to category overlaps?  Thanks for the discussion.  I'll grant the green arrow because I guess it doesn't really matter about how to clean up a spelling error in tags.

Comment: I know. For a real taxonomist, "meta" would probably mean something different :) The real problem at hand is that "tweaking" can mean so many things. // You mean subscribing to tag combinations? I have never used that feature — I think it's best if you opened a new `[support]` question!